# NSAutoLayoutContraint for iPhone 6Plus

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, iphone-6-plus, autolayout

Following is an image from iPhone6 having a simple view.

Constraint details are as follows.

[image: Constraint Details]

[image: iPhone6]

But on iPhone 6 Plus, It starts getting margins from left & right.
Very easy to notice by looking at space before text 'Carrier' & space after battery icon in given images.

[image: iPhone 6Plus]

Question 1: Why do we add -16 as margin to leading and trailing space when adding a constraint to main/parent/super view?

Question 2: Why -16 margin works only for iPhone 6Plus & not for other phones?

Comment: -16 works even on other iPhones. Also, please note you need -20 for iPad.

Comment: Currently focusing on iPhone App only :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unselected `Constrain to margin` when you set your constraints

[image]

Comment: This can also be set after the constraint is set in the size inspector on the right side when a constraint is set. Just unselect "relative to margin" in the first and second items.

Answer (score 0):

uncheck the "**Constrain to margin**" from constraint selection because this is a new feature of iOS8.

Comment: yes, uncheck "constrain to margin" bcz of new feature of iOS8, suppose you will not uncheck "constrain to margin" than your project will cruse apart from iOS8 device.